# Looking for a way to work with current "session" of Lotus Notes

Tags: c, lotus-notes

I'm wondering if there is a C function to work with the current "session" of Lotus Notes running in the Lotus C API Toolkit, similar to "NotesSession" in VBA. I wasn't able to find anything on the internet or going through the documentation. I need it to access the users calendar and modify it based on schedule from a different app. Currently it works with manual input of the database name and username.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the information you need from the notes.ini file using [OSGetEnvironmentString](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/85255d56004d3f6385255b3f004c535e?OpenDocument) to read the keys "mailfile" and "mailserver" and "username".  You can also use [SECKFMGetUserName](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/9.0/api90ref.nsf/61fd4e9848264ad28525620b006ba8bd/85255d56004d3f6385255bb100754a56?OpenDocument) to get the username.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's what I've been looking for.